# Must I upgrade Paypal account to business account in order to intergrate Paypal in Live Mode with my ASP.NET website using C#?

Tags: paypal

In order to integrate PayPal with my ASP.NET website using C#, I was told that "Sign up for a PayPal developer account and obtain API credentials. I will need to create a Sandbox account to test my application."

At present, I hope to use  Live Mode of Paypal instead of Sandbox Mode,  must I  upgrade Paypal account to business account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process live payments, you need a live business account. There is no reason not to upgrade, having one is free.